# C type * (blank) declaration (binary tree, case in point)

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Here is a piece of code that's confusing me.

```
struct tNode {
  int key;            // search key for this item
  int data;           // data for this item
  struct tNode *left, *right; // children
};

typedef struct tNode tree_type;

/**************** tree_new() ****************/
/* Create a new tree */
tree_type *
tree_new(const int key, const int data)
{
  tree_type *node = malloc(sizeof(struct tNode));

  ...
  }
}
```

So I'm not quite getting the syntax for `tree_type *` right above tree_new function. Doesn't seem like a pointer... not sure what it's doing there.

--------------------- post-edit
Thanks to all who helped out!

Comment: It is a pointer. `tree_new` returns a pointer-to-`tree_type`.

Comment: it's the return type of the function. It's a pointer all right...

Comment: Line breaks aren't special in C. It's just like you wrote `tree_type *tree_new(...` on one line.

Comment: `tree_type *node` is the pointer to receive the value returned from `malloc`. And `tree_type *tree_new()` specifies the return value of the function, a pointer to `tree_type`. The way the function is defined is a coding *style* I do not like. Any more than for a variable putting `int` on one line and `i;` on the next.

Comment: I created a more complete example that compiles and runs and puts the answer into a somewhat fuller/functional context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read both lines together:

```
tree_type *
tree_new(const int key, const int data)
```

is just another legal way to write the function definition with its return type:

```
tree_type *tree_new(const int key, const int data)
```

since it doesn't end with a semicolon, the statement continues on the next line(s).

Answer (score 3):

`tree_type *` is not a blank declaration. `tree_type` is a declaration specifier and `*` is the part of the declarator for the function `tree_new` (Thanks to @[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) for the nitpick).
That says, `tree_type *` depicts the return type of the function `tree_new`.

Comment: Strictly strictly, the `tree_type` is a _declaration_specifier_ and the `*` is part of the _declarator_ for the function.  But that's the nittiest of picks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Actually this is correct as per the language grammar. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *foobar(int x) {
    return 42;
}
```

is the same as

```
int *
foobar(int x)
{
    return 42;
}
```

Same thing with `tree_type` (or `struct tNode`).

Answer (score 1):

Your use of pointers look fine. Your `malloc()` returns a pointer to memory to a defined pointer type.  After seeing your small code, I thought you might benefit with suggestions for it and the context your binary tree example might be used in.

**typedef nameing convention**

Struct declaration and typedef can be done at the same time. That's a matter of preference. A common convention for typedefs in C is to name it in the form `someType_t`to have a consistent way of identifying typedefs everywhere they're used.

**Zeroing allocated memory**

I usually use `calloc()`, rather than `malloc()` because unlike `malloc()`, `calloc()` zeroes the allocated memory.

I might add the word `_safe` to the name of the allocation function (by convention), to indicate if it returns, it has succeeded (e.g. it's safe so a null-check in the calling layer is unnecessary).

**Safe allocation and checking for allocation failures**

The allocation does the null check and displays an explicit simple *out-of-memory* message if there isn't enough memory available. If the program is out of memory anywhere, that an usually be considered fatal and a justification to exit the program, because, if there isn't enough memory anywhere, things are likely to be failing everywhere. It would be a very rare program that has the sophistication to handle an out of memory condition robustly, such as being able to wait it out and retry until memory is available again, so simply exiting is common.  Using safe allocation functions will save you a lot of null-checking in the calling layer.

**Setting freed pointers to NULL**

Note the setting of the freed pointer to NULL. If this is done consistently then a pointer can always be determined to be valid or not by a NULL check.  Further, freeing NULL on most systems is a NOP, so in that way you can lower the risk of double free (freeing a pointer more than once), which can produce some disastrous and difficult to diagnose bugs, particularly in larger programs.

**Simple Binary Tree Example**
<sup>(compiles/runs)</sup>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Tree {
  int key;            
  int data;           
  struct Tree *left, *right; 
} tree_t;

// Dummy data just for example:

#define KEY  1
#define VAL  2
#define KEY2 3
#define VAL2 4
#define KEY3 5
#define VAL3 6

tree_t *node_create_safe(const int, const int);
void free_tree(tree_t *);

int 
main() {
   tree_t *rootNode = node_create_safe(KEY, VAL);
   rootNode->left   = node_create_safe(KEY2, VAL2);;
   rootNode->right  = node_create_safe(KEY3, VAL3);;
   free_tree(rootNode);  
   rootNode = NULL;     
}

/* 
 * node_create_safe() - allocates node, always returns pointer. 
 *
 *      Side effects: Terminates program on allocation failure.
 */
tree_t *
node_create_safe(const int key, const int data) {
  tree_t *node = calloc(sizeof(struct Tree), 1);
  if (node == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
      exit(-1);
  }
  node->key = key;
  node->data = data;
  return node;
}

/*
 * free_tree() - Recursively frees [sub]tree
 */
void
free_tree(tree_t *node) {
     if (node->left != NULL) 
         free_tree(node->left);
     if (node->right != NULL)
         free_tree(node->right);
     free(node);
}
```